# How to override steps-wizard template file in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, layout, template

How to override the steps-wizard template file in Magento 2.3?
I need to override **`Magento_ConfigurableProduct::catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/select_attributes.phtml`**.

above file define in **`vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_wizard.xml`**

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the `catalog_product_wizard.xml` at the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_wizard.xml

Now added code like this one :

```
<block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Steps\SelectAttributes" name="step1" template="Vendor_Extension::catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/select_attributes.phtml">
   ..................                 
</block>
```

2. Now create `select_attributes.phtml` at following location :

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\edit\attribute\steps\select_attributes.phtml

And added your custom code there.